# Swap characters in a string using shell script

Tags: shell

I need to swap characters of a string (which is mmddyyyy format) and rearrange them in yyyymmdd. This string is obtained from a file name (`abc_def_08032011.txt`).

```
string=$(ls abc_def_08032011.txt | awk '{print substr($0,9,8)}')
```

For example:

- Current string: `08032011` (This may not necessarily be the current date)
- Desired string: `20110803`

I tried split function, but it won't work since the string does not have any delimiter.

Any ideas/suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: bash, tcsh, or any other shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using awk all the way:

```
echo abc_def_08032011.txt | awk '{print substr($0,13,4) substr($0,9,4)}'
```

or sed all the way, avoiding one awk:

```
echo abc_def_08032011.txt | sed 's/^........\(....\)\(....\).*$/\2\1/'
```

or using ksh substitution all the way to avoid spawning a awk/sed process:

```
s=abc_def_08032011.txt
s1="${s#????????}"
s2="${s1%.*}"
echo "${s2#????}${s2%????}"
```

Answer (score 4):

`echo 08032011 | sed 's/\(....\)\(....\)/\2\1/'`

or

`echo 08032011 | perl -pe 's/(....)(....)/$2$1/'`

Comment: @pinhead: It took me just a moment to realize that that's your user name.  8-)}  Note that it's quite inflexible.  There are a number of other possibilities that, for example, search for sequences of digits.  But if you're sure what the input looks like and don't need error checking, that's fine.

Comment: the input will pretty much stay in the same format, so we need not worry about error checking. I am still new to using sed, it would really help if you could explain me how the extended regular expressions work in your given solution?Thanks.