# How do I swap number position such as 4th position to 7th position?

Tags: linux, sed

Example number:

```
12345678
```

My attempt:

```
sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)/\2\1/'
```

My Result:

```
21345678
```

This line here would swap the first position and second position of number. I can't seem to figure out how to do with a further position yet.

Comment: [Swap characters in specific positions in strings of varying lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12551917/608639), [Swap characters in a string using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6932335/608639), [sed command to swap characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207039/56041), [Replacing some characters in a string with another character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2871181/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to modify it to capture more groups, and output them in the desired sequence:

```
sed 's/^(...)(.)(..)(.)/\1\4\3\2/'
#      |  |   |  |   |
#      |  |   |  |   +- digit #7(\4)
#      |  |   |  +----- 2 chars (\3)
#      |  |   +-------- digit #4 (\2)
#      |  +------------ 3 chars (\1)
#      +--------------- start-of-line anchor
```

Keep in mind this is for the simplest case where you just want to swap character positions regardless of whether they're digits or not. You can easily re-expand the character classes to limit what gets swapped but my intent here is just to show the simplest way to achieve a swap.

Comment: Thank you. I've just started so everything is new to me

Comment: I suggest to add option `-E` or `-r`.

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the 4th letter and 7th one with:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\)/\1\4\3\2/' <<< "12345678"
```

output:

```
12375648
```

Comment: Absolutely yes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a lot cleaner to use `awk`:

```
$ echo 12345678 | awk '{t=$4; $4=$7; $7=t}1' FS= OFS=
12375648
```

Comment: The effect of setting FS to null is undefined behavior per POSIX. It'll do what you want in gawk and maybe some other awks but in others still it'll do other things, e.g. treat the whole input line as a single field.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/./\n&/7;s//\n&/4;s/\n(.)(.*)\n(.)/\3\2\1/' file
```

Introduce a newline at the character positions and use pattern matching to swap those characters.

N.B. The normal flow of the replacement must be reversed otherwise the introduced newline will effect the length of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

With a sed that supports EREs via the `-E` option, e.g. GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed:

```
$ echo '12345678' | sed -E 's/(.{3})(.)(.{2})(.)/\1\4\3\2/'
12375648
```